# Tooltip reputation detail gone from users page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips, top-users

Until very recently (yesterday or this morning UK time), when you mouse over the reputation change score of a given user on the [Users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users), you got to see the precise reputation change for the selected period.

The pages themselves show *rounded* values for larger reputation changes (anything over 10k). For example, Jon Skeet got *roughly* 101k reputation so far this year. The tooltip on the '101k' would show you how much *exactly* he gained this year.

Not so anymore today:

[image: no more exact rep]

Now (at rev 2013.11.4.1115) we just get the rather meaningless 'reputation score' text, which surely cannot be intentional. Can we have the exact values back please?

Note, the 'all time' page doesn't suffer from this problem, the other pages do.

Comment: Does it do the same on comments? Try hovering over my username over there --->

Comment: @Undo: It works just fine on comments. So far only the Users listings appear affected.

Comment: What is it with the downvotes on acknowledged bugreports? I'd love to hear a motivation for why *that*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.

Regression around localizing reputation tooltips, missed the case (and a few `string.Format()`'s) where we showed weekly/monthly/quarterly/yearly reputation instead of full reputation.